# Why is my image not following the divs class?

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to html, here is my code:

```css
.social-media {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-media">
  <a href="https://twitter.com/mytwitter" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/limav/flat-gradient-social/256/Twitter-icon.png" alt="my twitter">
  </a>
</div>
```

the twitter image is not changing from the css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
  .social-media img {
     height: 100px;
     width: 100px;
     border-radius: 25px;
  }
```

Comment: If this solution worked for you, you should to mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Add Separate style for image to make it occupy full width of the parent

```css
  .social-media {
     height: 100px;
     width: 100px;
     border-radius: 25px;
  }
  .social-media img{
     width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="social-media">
  <a href="https://twitter.com/mytwitter" target="_blank"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/limav/flat-gradient-social/256/Twitter-icon.png" alt="my twitter"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css is not targeting the image directly :

1. give your image an Id or Class so you target that specifically

```css
.social-media-image {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-media">
  <a href="https://twitter.com/mytwitter" target="_blank">
    <img class="social-media-image" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/limav/flat-gradient-social/256/Twitter-icon.png" alt="my twitter">
  </a>
</div>
```

2. you could target the image directly from the social media class

```css
.social-media img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-media">
  <a href="https://twitter.com/mytwitter" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/limav/flat-gradient-social/256/Twitter-icon.png" alt="my twitter">
  </a>
</div>
```

check out [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) *on how css selector work*

Comment: .social-media img is a better option. No need to add additional class statement.

Comment: @spa900 yes it is if you have one image or you want them all to be the same size